# How to add a new column based on the value in the field `time`

Tags: mysql

I have table:

```
+--------+--------------+-----------+   
| person |.....DAY......| ....hours |  
| Name1 ....2014-01-08... 03:53:23  |   
| Name2 ....2014-01-08... 05:30:54  |  
+--------|--------------|-----------+
```

How can I add a new column `label` based on the value in the field of time?
If time from 05:00:00 to 11:00:00 the value will be `'1'`, else `'0'`. It should look something like this:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------+---------+  
| person  |.....DAY......| ..hours  |  label   |   
| Name1 ....2014-01-08... 03:53:23  |  0 ......|   
| Name2 ....2014-01-08... 05:30:54  |  1.......|   
+---------+--------------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a calculated column you can generate it on-the-fly in your queries like this

```
SELECT person, 
       DATE( dt ) AS DAY , 
       case when hour(from_unixtime(sec_to_time(SUM( IF( source LIKE '%вход' OR source LIKE '%въезд', -1, 1 ) * UNIX_TIMESTAMP( dt ) )))) between 5 and 11 
            then 1
            else 0 
       end AS hours
from your_table
```

Comment: What to do if my column `hours` declared in SELECT:             

SELECT person, DATE( dt ) AS 
DAY , sec_to_time(SUM( IF(  `source` LIKE  '%вход' OR `source` LIKE  '%въезд', -1, 1 ) * UNIX_TIMESTAMP( dt ) )) AS hours

Answer (score 3):

you can use something like this

```
update table set label = case when hour(hours) between 5 and 10 then 0 else 1 end;
```